# How to deserialize Empty Json payload using DataContractJsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8.1

Below is the Json key value that I am trying to Deserialize using DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(ms). Problem here is key "Modified_date" can have Empty payload as well for which Deserialization is failing.

Modified_date:
{ 
date: "2016-02-05 02:12:43.000000", 
timezone_type: 3, 
timezone: "America/Chicago" 
}

Comment: Use Json.NET nuget package for parse json .

Comment: Thanks Kushal, it worked !!